# Why do we take $\pi r^2 P = -\eta 2\pi r l(dv/dr)$ in the derivation of velocity expression while deriving Poiseuille's equation of fluid flow?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity

Let us consider a cylindrical tube of length $l$ and radius a through which a liquid is flowing. Pressure at the liquid entering and out going side are respectively $P_1$ and $P_2$ ($P_1 > P_2$). Thus the pressure difference between the two end of the tube is $(P_1 - P_2) = P$.

Then we assume a cylindrical surface of the liquid at distance $r$ from the axis and find out the viscous force on that cylindrical surface which is equal to $-\eta 2 \pi rl(dv/dr)$. Our next job was to find out the part of  force which is applied from outside by creating the pressure difference to balance the viscous force so that there was acceleration of the liquid.

In my book and  many websites I found that the part of force which balances the viscous force ($-\eta 2 \pi r l (dv/dr)$) arising at distance $r$ on the cylindrical surface is $\pi r^2 P$. But how can these two forces be equal? If we use simple concept of force and pressure then we will get forces on our imaginary liquid cylinder of radius $r$ from liquid entering and out going side are respectively $\pi r^2 P_1$ and $\pi r^2 P_2$. No other forces are acting on that imaginary liquid cylinder from outside. So total force acting from outside on the liquid cylinder is $(\pi r^2 P_1 - \pi r^2 P_2) = \pi r^2(P_1 - P_2) = \pi r^2 P$ (minus because the forces are opposite in direction).

But we can't simply equal this $\pi r^2 P$ force with the viscous force $-\eta 2 \pi r l (dv/dr)$ as the viscous force $-\eta 2 \pi r l (dv/dr)$ is acting on the cylindrical liquid surface at distance r from the axis but the $\pi r^2 P$ force is acting on the whole liquid cylinder of radius $r$. So this $\pi r^2 P$ force is working to overcome all the viscous forces that is arising between all the possible layers between the radius  $r = 0$ to $r = r$. Then why will we equal this $\pi r^2 P$ force only with the viscous force that is arising on the topmost surface of our imaginary cylinder? (note: all the postulates of Poiseuille's equation are applicable here, so the pressure difference is completely utilised to overcome viscous force)

Comment: When you do a force balance, you only include the external forces acting on your designated region.  In this case, the external force is the viscous frictional force exerted by the fluid outside of radius r on the fluid inside the radius r.  This is the viscous force at the surface r.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding between boundary conditions of the cylindrical system and those of a small differential element on which the force balance is done.

So let's start from the beginning; consider a cylindrical differential volume $dV = A_c dr dz$. This DV is experiencing an axial pressure force and a radial viscous force, which (in steady-state and if other mechanisms are negligible) must be balance, i.e. accumulation = incoming - outgoing:

$$ 0 = \left.pA_c\right|_z - \left.pA_c\right|_{z+dz} + \left.\tau_{rz}A_s\right|_r - \left.\tau_{rz}A_s\right|_{r+dr}$$

where $\left.p\right|_z$ is the pressure at an axial coordinate $z$ and $\left.\tau_{rz}\right|_r$ is the axial component of the shear stress at radial coordinate $r$. $A_c = 2\pi rdr$ is the area of the cylinder the pressure $p$ is acting on and $A_s = 2\pi rdz$ is the surface area of the cylinder the shear stress is acting on.

Let's use the definiton of derivatives to write this in differential form:
$$0=-\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(pA_c\right)dz-\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\tau_{rz}A_s\right)dr$$

Substitute in the formula for the areas and rearranging:
$$0=-\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}2\pi r dr dz-\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\tau_{rz}\right)2\pi dr dz$$
$$-\frac{\partial p}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\tau_{rz}\right)$$

This is the most general differential form of a viscous fluid in a cylindrical system driven by a pressure gradient.

Now the left-hand side is only a function of the axial coordinate $z$ whereas the right-hand side only of the radial coordinate $r$; this can only be the case if both are a constant, say $K$:

$$-\frac{\partial p}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\tau_{rz}\right) = K$$

This implies a linear function of the pressure:

$$p\left(z\right)=-Kz+C_1$$

Applying pressure boundary conditions $p(z=0)=p_1$ and $p(z=L)=p_2$:

$$C_1 = p_1 \quad K = \frac{p_1 - p_2}{L} = -\frac{\Delta p}{L} \quad \Delta p = p_2 - p_1$$

And it implies a linear function for the shear stress:

$$r\tau_{rz}\left(r\right)= \frac{1}{2}Kr^2 + C_2 = \frac{1}{2}Kr^2$$

where $C_2=0$ because the stress vanishes at the center, i.e. $\tau_{rz}\left(r=0\right) = 0$.

From here we can see that by rearranging and substituting in some values:

$$-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\Delta p}{L}r^2 = r\tau_{rz}\left(r\right)$$
$$\pi r^2 \Delta p = -2\pi r L \tau_{rz}\left(r\right)$$

and if we the assume a newtonian fluid, i.e. $\tau_{rz}\left(r\right)=-\eta\left.\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial r}\right|_r$, we arrive at:

$$\pi r^2 \Delta p = 2\pi r L \eta \left.\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial r}\right|_r$$

What does this mean? Well basically because the gradients of both pressure and shear stress in the control volume are constants we can simply balance the pressure force $\Delta p A_c = \pi r^2\Delta p$ with the shear force $\tau_{rz}A_s = 2\pi r L \tau_{rz}$.